# How to fix `Invalid component name` when changing page with custom layout in nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js

`[Vue warn]: Invalid component name: "layouts/default.vue". Component names should conform to valid custom element name in html5 specification.`

As you ca see in above error I'm facing a problem when i used custom layout for my Auth page. Problem is when i go to Auth page with custom layout, i don't get any error, but anytime i try to back from Auth page, I'll get above error. when i do success `login/register` or just hit Back button I'll get that warning on loading homepage

Here's default layout which is located in default place when nuxt installed :

```
<template>
      <v-main>
            <v-flex>
              <Nuxt />
            </v-flex>
      </v-main>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    components: {AppHeader, AppFooter},
    async fetch () {
      try {
        const layout= await this.$axios.$get('/app')
        this.app= layout;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    },
    data() {
      return{
        app: null,
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Original Answer**

Well problem was the `async fetch` in default layout which i replaced it with `nuxtServerInit`. when i switch layout nuxt wanted to call api again because async fetch should load again since it's loading again after auth layout switch. So i replaced it with `nuxtServerInit` to prevent this warning to happen.

Good Luck

**Small Update and Clarification**

So, I'll try to explain more about the situation that I've got back days to clarify how this issue happened.

You might not have any problem in using `async fetch`, which is also deprecated in `Nuxt 2`, but this actually was in most of tutorials, and in term of using multiple layouts for application base on specific routes, `async fetch` was causing this issue when, changes in layout was dynamically happening.

The application I was creating had `Dynamic Page Render` like `Wordpress` and in term of different type of page, I've developed `Dynamic Layout changer`, but using `async fetch` was causing this issue when i was going back to another layout to main layout which it was doing `async fetch`.

For some people who are using `Vue` they might had this issue when they hadn't `name : {layoutName}`, but in term of my kind of application which it was quite complicated, problem was using `async fetch` which it was deprecated in `Nuxt 2`, instead of `NuxtServerInit`.

So in general, you can use `async fetch` or etc. But in layout on first attempt, you should use `NuxtServerInit` to get data to render the primary data or etc.

Answer (score 17):

I managed to fix this by adding name attribute to the layout...

### layouts/default.vue

```
 export default {
  name: "default"
  ...
}
```

And the error is gone

Comment: This works, however, you may want to hold to some of the eslint vuejs options. In this case `vue/component-definition-name-casing`. This rule states you should use PascalCasing. So instead of `default` you should use `Default` or even better `DefaultLayout`

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is in selecting the name in two component you use 'auth' as name of component that I think make the problem.

```
   export default {
    name: "auth"
   }
```

Both in  "Auth Layout"  and "Auth Page :"

Comment: Thanks but problem was because of fetch in default.